# How to output or redirect GHC compile errors to a file instead of standard output?

Tags: haskell, ghc

I'm trying to compile a haskell file that has a HUGE number of errors in it.  I want to start debugging the first one but unfortunately there are so many that they go off the screen.

I want to pipe the error messages to a file so that I can read from the top, but normal methods don't seem to work.

I've tried:

```
ghc File.hs > errors.log
ghc File.hs >> errors.log
ghc File.hs | more
```

None of them work.  Using `>` and `>>` only writes the first couple of lines to the file and then the rest to standard output.  Using `more`, `less`, `cat` etc doesn't make any difference at all.

Is there a flag for GHC that will let me output to a file?

(I should probably let you know that I'm working on a Windows machine with Cygwin.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Most programs write output to the standard output (file descriptor `1`) and error messages to the standard error (file descriptor `2`).

You can ask your shell to redirect the standard error to another location like this:

```
ghc File.hs > output.log 2> errors.log
```

or if you want them in the same file:

```
ghc File.hs > output.log 2>&1
```

See your shell's manpage section of redirections for full details. Note that the shells are picky about the order of the redirections.

Comment: Thank you! It's so obvious now you mention it.

Answer (score 4):

You can also view the output directly, using the same redirect as sarnold's solution, but without the intermediate output file:

```
ghc File.hs 2>&1 | less
```

(same goes for `more` instead of `less`, etc.)

Comment: When I was hunting around the `bash(1)` manpage to make sure I got the order in my answer correct, I found the `|&` token -- you can use `gch File.hs |& less` to do the same thing! 18 years I've been using Linux and _today_ I learn this. Amazing. :)